# Detect type of JSON attribute

Tags: java, android

JSON:

```
{"attribute1":11, "attribute2":"string atribute"}
```

I want to detect what kind of type are attribute1 and attribute2:

- attribute1 is integer
- attribute2 is string

jsonObject.getAttributeType("attribute2"); // should output: string/integer/boolean.

It was very easy to achieve in PHP or OBJC. Suggestions?

Comment: Can't you use jsonObject.get() and check result with instanceof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm assuming that the Android for the `org.json` package is that same as you can find on the json.org site ... [here](http://www.json.org/java/index.html).)

The only method on a `JSONObject` that will give you the underlying value ... without coercing it ... is `JSONObject.get(name)`.  If `name` is known, the result is the object that represents the value internally.  I haven't done a comprehensive trawl of the code, but I think it can only be one of the following types:

```
  Boolean, Long, Double, String, JSONArray, JSONObject
```

You should be able to discriminate these using `instanceof`.

---

But should be asking yourself if this is the right thing to do.  The *normal* way to deal with JSON object attributes via the `JSONObject` API is to use the methods that coerce them into the type that you expect.  In most cases, it doesn't matter if a number is sent as `42` or `42.0` or `"42"` ... and it is best not to be picky if the intent is easy to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you can use the **jackson** library to do this,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader;

//Defining the JSON object
JSON json = {"attribute1":11, "attribute2":"string atribute"};

//Get the needed attribute
String value = json.get("attribute1");

//Convert the attribute to JsonNode
JsonNode value = JsonLoader.fromString(value);

//Then you can check type as below
value.isObject();
value.isArray();
value.isDouble();
value.isTextual();
value.isInt()
```